# Visual Basic BMI Calculator gives NaN result

Tags: vb.net, calculator

I'm doing an IT course for college and one of the assignments requires you to create a BMI calculator in Visual Basic with the use of object orientated techniques. I'm not a very good programmer and thus I'm stuck on a problem I keep receiving. The code I'm using was given to me by someone who claimed it works, however when I run the program any results given are NaN.

Anyone have an idea as to what is wrong with the code in order to give me this result?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button_Calculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
Button_Calculate.Click
    Dim height As Double = Double.Parse(TextBox_Height.Text)
    Dim weight As Double = Double.Parse(TextBox_Weight.Text)


    bmi.SetWeight(weight)
    bmi.SetHeight(height)

    TextBox_BMI.Text = Format(bmi.GetBMI(), "0.00")
End Sub

Private bmi As New BMI
End Class
```

In a separate class:

```
Public Class BMI
Public Function GetBMI()
    Return (weight / (height ^ 2))
End Function

Public Function GetWeight()
    Return weight
End Function
Public Function GetHeight()
    Return height
End Function

Public Function SetWeight(_weight As Double)
    Return weight = _weight
End Function
Public Function SetHeight(_height As Double)
    Return height = _height
End Function

Private weight As Double
Private height As Double
End Class
```

Comment: The problem here is that VB.NET does not support inline assignment. `Return weight = _weight` will first evaluate if `weight` equals `_weight`, then return the resulting Boolean (`True` or `False`). You need to set `weight = _weight` separately and then `Return weight`.

Comment: If this is actual code then you are running your compiler with `Option Strict Off` (which is the default). If you change it to `Option Strict On` then the compiler will find many of your errors before you can even run your code. If I try to compile your `BMI` class then I get the error `"BC30210 Option Strict On requires all Function, Property, and Operator declarations to have an 'As' clause."`. That will force you to declare the return type of your functions, which would then clear up the issue with the lines `Return weight = _weight`.

Comment: However, the two `SetWeight` & `SetHeight` methods should be `Sub` not `Function` and that'll clear up the problems too.

Comment: Regarding your point about "the code was given to me" I'd politely suggest having a read of this. I'm not judging, but the ideas  on the linked page are very inciteful.. [Open letter to Students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: @DavidWilson Yes I understand your point, I'm simply too pressed on time to learn it on my own and thus I needed a base to work with.

Comment: @Enigmativity - I would also say those two methods should be eliminated and changed to a property instead.  For both weight and height.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems with your (meaning kushlord420) solution.

1. Visual Basic code in case insensitive so bmi is the same as BMI
2. You never use the Form level variable bmi so delete.
3. You tried to write a custom constructor but in vb.net it is Sub New
4. You are converting the values in the weight and height text boxes to Double but your properties are type Single. Actually this should
       be Single.TryParse but that is for another day.
5. Functions in vb.net must have a data type for the return value. This is provided in the first line of the function. Since you are
   using Format on the return value I made the value a String and
   converted the return value.
6. Fixed the constructor parameters to avoid ambiguity.

```vb
    Sub Button_Calculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_Calculate.Click
        Dim bmi As New BMI(CSng(TextBox_Weight.Text), CSng(TextBox_Height.Text))
        TextBox_BMI.Text = Format(bmi.GetBMI(), "0.00")
    End Sub

    Public Class BMI
        Public Function GetBMI() As String
            Return (Weight / (Height ^ 2)).ToString
        End Function

        Public Property Weight As Single
        Public Property Height As Single

        Public Sub New(wght As Single, hght As Single)
            Weight = wght
            Height = hght
        End Sub
    End Class
```

Comment: @Visual Vincent Thanks for the clean up on my formatting. I thought I had made great strides when I learned to add `<!-- language: lang-vb.net -->` above my code so I could use a numbered list. Could barely bet this to format at all, maybe because the first line was not part of the list.

Comment: Why `Public Weight As Single` & `Property Height As Single`?? Also, why change to `Single`? `Double` is much better.

Comment: @Enigmativity Just an oops on the public & property. Thanks for the correction. As far as the single, I was correcting solution posted by the OP and that had weight and height as single.

Comment: @Mary : Actually it should be either `<!-- language: lang-vb -->` or `<!-- language: vb.net -->`. `lang-vb.net` is not valid :). Though your first line was actually part of the list, however you had indented your other lines too much so they became a nested list _under_ the first list.

Answer (score 1):

You really need something more like this:

```
Public Class BMI
    Public Function GetBMI() As Double
        Return (weight / (height ^ 2))
    End Function

    Public Property Weight As Double
    Public Property Height As Double

    Public Sub New(weight As Double, height As Double)
        Me.Weight = weight
        Me.Height = height
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button_Calculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_Calculate.Click
        Dim bmi As New BMI(CDbl(TextBox_Weight.Text), CDbl(TextBox_Height.Text))
        TextBox_BMI.Text = Format(bmi.GetBMI(), "0.00")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Or better yet, this:

```
Public Class BMI

    Public Property Weight As Double
    Public Property Height As Double

    Public ReadOnly Property BMI As Double
        Get
            Return (Weight / (Height ^ 2))
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(weight As Double, height As Double)
        Me.Weight = weight
        Me.Height = height
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score -1):

With the help of a friend, figured out my problem.

If anyone is curious, here is the code that made it work:

```
Public Class Form1
 Sub Button_Calculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
Button_Calculate.Click
  Dim bmi As New BMI With {.Weight = CDbl(TextBox_Weight.Text), .Height = 
  CDbl(TextBox_Height.Text)}
  TextBox_BMI.Text = Format(bmi.GetBMI(), "0.00")
End Sub


Private bmi As New BMI
End Class
```

And:

```
Public Class BMI
Public Function GetBMI()
    Return (weight / (height ^ 2))
End Function

Property Weight As Single
Property Height As Single

Public Sub BMI(weight As Single, height As Single)
    Me.Weight = weight
    Me.Height = height
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You should change `Public Sub BMI(...)` to `Public Sub New(...)` instead, then you can shorten your code to: `Dim bmi As New BMI(CDbl(TextBox_Weight.Text), CDbl(TextBox_Height.Text))`

Comment: Why change to `Single`? `Double` is better.

Comment: @Enigmativity Why is double better? I'm not really a programmer, and I'm only doing this for a college assignment, where it doesn't really matter as long as the code works as intended.

Comment: @kushlord420 - The CPU works using `Double`. Even if you have a `Single` it is converted to `Double` for computation. The only advantage is memory if you have exceedingly large lists. You also get far smaller rounding errors with `Double`.